# Is Latent Class Analysis considered as generative or discriminative?

Tags: classification

As title.

It would be great if someone could point me to the derivation, where I can judge myself if it is discriminative or generative?

Better still, is there a way to figure out the answer without going through the derivation (e.g., via intuitive explanation)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a Latent Class Model is a special case of a mixture model. Thus, a fitted Latent Class Model is a probability distribution. Hence, a Latent Class Model is a generative model.